# Pocketsphinx cannot decode mfc file while pocketsphinx_continuous decodes corresponding wav

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have been working with CMUsphinx for Turkish language speech to text for couple months. I have succeeded to run a train on a 100 hours of sound. My target was to use the resulting Acoustic Model with Sphinx3 decoder. However Sphinx3 decoder cannot decode my test wav files. Then I have noticed that sphinxtrain runs pocketsphinx_batch in the end of training for testing the model.

So, I started working on poscketsphinx. I am at a point where pocketsphinx batch cannot decode a wav file (actually it only produces ııı nothing else) but pocketsphinx continuous produces more meaningful output with the same file (e.g. 10 correct words out of 15 words).

I guess I am missing some configuration steps. I have an compressed archive in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eow97appz4gbsj9/SahinStackOF.tar.bz2?dl=0)
 which includes the Acoustic and language models, dictionary and wav files I try to decode.

I am asking to get help for being able to use my model with Sphinx3 and Pocketsphinx_batch.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information which command do you run exactly. What do you see as an output and what is wrong with it.

Comment: The command I used for pocketsphinx_batch is given in this text file. It seems to produce only the word ııı.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f15saynp0u52ubu/pocketsphinx_batch_output.txt?dl=0

Comment: I used the same wav file along with same Acoustic Model, Language Model and Dictionary in pocketsphinx_continuous and the output is given here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdwpr4xo2bieg28/pocketsphinx_continuous_output.txt?dl=0

pocketsphinx_continuous decodes the wav file to "gibi seçim camiasına bin dokuz yüz seksende giderken geçmişte yanlış ondan sonra uzun yolculuğa çıkmış birkaç güne özetleyecek savaşlar barışa" which is not very accurate but still valuable.

Comment: Ok, and what is the pocketsphinx_continuous output? And how did you extract mfcc file?

Comment: I have edited my question above. The problem were the mfc files. In the training sphinx_fe had used different parameters than it has as default. I created the mfc files with the parameters used in the training. Now it is OK.

Comment: Congratulations, you can write an answer and accept it then.

Comment: Thank you very much @NikolayShmyrev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I found the problem. It was feature vectors which are produced by sphinx_fe. I was creating them with default values. After reading the make_feats.pl and sphinxtrain.cfg files, I created feature vectors compatible with the Acoustic Model. Sphinxtrain.cfg has the lifter parameter as 22, but if we use sphinx_fe with default values lifter is 0, which means no lifter. I created mfc with lifter value 22 then it worked.